# add an item to a list inside a nested map in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I call `addItemToCart({"key": "val"})`, I'm having trouble to add the item to a list inside a nested map in Dart/Flutter. `var list = cart['items']` gave back me a null, but I initialized class member `cart` already.

What's really wrong with it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:collection';

class PData extends ChangeNotifier {
  dynamic cart = {"items": []};

  int itemCount = 0;
  String uid;
  String phoneNumber;

  void addItemToCart(val){
    var list = cart['items'];
    print("list ");
    print (list);

    list.add(val);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

}

Gives the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 5763): list 
I/flutter ( 5763): null

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

Tried calling: add(_LinkedHashMap len:6)

Comment: Is you `cart` variable also null ?

Comment: It seem like the list is not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add .toList() to initiate. See the sample code snippet below :

```
var list = cart['items'];
var realList = list.toList();
print("list ");
print (list);

realList.add("soap");
print(realList);  // This prints [soap]
realList.add("Pen");
print(realList); // This prints [soap, pen]
```